# WCF response from void method

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, c#-4.0, soap

I am trying to access WCF service. Please check image 1 [image: Image1]

Please check image 2 of how to implement the service.
[image: Image2]

The method is void and it says it writtens Workspaceid in the response which i am looking for.

This is how i am implementing

```
  CreativeAssetServiceClient creativeAssetServiceClient = new CreativeAssetServiceClient();
 creativeAssetServiceClient.CreateWorkspace(token, creativeTags, filenameWithoutExtension, filenameWithoutExtension, file, ref folder);
```

I am able to create the workspace but the workspaceid is coming in response and i dont know how to get the response because the method is void. I tried to convert void into string but it does not work. Can anyone tell me how can i get the response workspaceid. Help would be appreciated .Thanks

Comment: variable "folder" in client side does not have response??? folder is marked with ref keyword.It should have response you are looking for

Comment: so the folder value i am passing it is the workspace id?

Comment: Thats what the specification says....Image 2 is code at client side or service side?

Comment: see the last line in method....workspace id which is ref parameter is set with value (retval.WorkspaceId).....just use folder variable in client side to get workspace id.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WorkspaceId is being returned in "folder" variable. Note: folder variable is marked with ref keyword. In WCf, ref keyword indicates that data is returned from service. so in this case folder variable which is workspace id is returened as reponse from service.

Answer (score 0):

`WorkspaceId` is a **ref** param, so your data will be in **folder** param.